# Can I programmatically update a wix.com website?

Tags: python, velo

I have a wix.com website with a number of sections including a blog. Each day I have a number of Python scripts that run and generate dynamic content. Mostly in tabular form. Like so:

```
2017-03-21  306.67  2017-05-17  308.16  closed  0.49 %
2017-04-13  305.45  2017-05-17  308.16  closed  0.89 %
2017-05-17  308.16  2017-06-02  311.88  open    3.43 %
```

Currently we are cutting and pasting the content, but I would like to update the blog section of the site automatically each day when the scripts run. Is there a way to do this? Python would be my language of choice, but I am open to any workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a work around using either the wix.com table app or their Google Docs app. Either of those appear to automatically update based on changes a Google doc. The update cycle appears to be every five minutes. Here is a local thread on programmatically updating Google Docs.

[Programatically updating a spreadsheet hosted on google docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837937/programatically-updating-a-spreadsheet-hosted-on-google-docs)

This seems like a long way around, but it may work.

https://www.wix.com/app-market/table-master/overview
https://www.wix.com/app-market/google-docs/overview

I'll test this and circle back.

Comment: Here is a nice worked example using Python with the Google Sheets API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python